# Python list comprehension ignore None results?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, list-comprehension

I have the following toy example function and list comprehension:

```
def foo(lst):
    if lst:
        return lst[0] + lst[1]

[foo(l) for l in [[], [1,2], [1,4]]]
```

The result is:

```
[None, 3, 4]
```

How can I avoid the `None`s, I would like to avoid calling `if foo(l) is not None` inside the list comp.
Please advise.

Comment: A list comprehension will output a value for every input unless you filter it. Why not test for `l` in the comprehension `[foo(l) for l in [[], [1,2], [1,4]] if l]` instead.

Comment: @Mark because here it's just a toy example, in my real case I am running fuzzy logic and sending the text and the possible choices, so I don't know in advance if it will return None or the relevant dictionary.

Comment: You might be better off with a generator in that case that calls `foo()` and decides whether to yield the value or not based on the result. That will let you avoid calling `foo()` twice and also avoid making a large list and filtering.

Comment: @Mark would you be so kind and show me an example? Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid calling the function more than once, you can make a generator that yields based on the result of the function. It's a little more code, but avoids making a list with a bunch of `None` values which have to be filtered later, and also avoids calling the function twice in the list comprehension:

```
def expensive_function(lst):
    # sometimes returns None...hard to know when without calling
    if lst:
        return lst[0] + lst[1]

def gen_results(l):
    for a in l:
        res = expensive_function(a)
        if res:
            yield res
    
inp = [[], [1,2], [1,4]]

list(gen_results(inp))
# [3, 5]
```

Also, since generators are lazy, you don't need to make a list if you don't need a list.

Comment: Why do I need ```yield```?

Comment: `yield` is what tells the generator to generate a value back to the caller. As it goes through the loop, it will spit out a value if the value is truthy. You don't want `return` here because that would end the function before the loop is done. See: [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators)

Answer (score 0):

As per OP request the following

- uses a list comprehension
- does not repeat a call to foo(l):

```py
[
   a 
   for l in [[], [1,2], [1,4]]]
   for a in (foo(l),)
   if a is not None
]
```